# .ASPXAUTH Cookie Not Found in Request.Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am creating a web application that is hosted under a web site with forms authentication enabled.  I have a role in my authentication database "Admins".  Here is my controller code:

```
[RequireHttps]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admins")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return this.View();
}
```

When I go to the Index page, if I'm not authenticated, it redirects me to the login page where I enter my credentials.  The login page then redirects back to Index page of the new app, but the controller doesn't recognize that the user is authenticated.

I have taken the `Authorize` attribute off and looked at the request as it went out in the Chrome developer console and confirmed that the cookie is indeed being sent.  But if I leave the `Authorize` attribute as is, and go to the Index page, the cookie collection on the request in my controller is empty.  The headers collection contains a header entitled "Cookie", and the value of the header contains the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

The login page calls logs in with this code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, remember, "/");
```

This behavior is reproducible in all major browsers.

What can I do to cause the Cookies collection of the request to be populated?
What do I need to do to make the application realize that the user really is authenticated?

**Edit:**
I still don't have it working, but I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the ASPXAUTH cookie being filtered.

Comment: Could you post the code of Login action where you authenticate user? Does it happen in all browsers or Chrome only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are multiple causes of this problem.  In my case, the problem was that the version of MVC I was using to write the cookie was different from the version that was decrypting it.  I changed my sites to all be running MVC 4, and the cookie that was created by one site was consumable by the other site.

Comment: How did you have two versions of MVC for the same project?

Comment: It was two separate projects that used the same cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Is the .ASPXAUTH cookie generated a secure cookie, i.e. SSL? If so and your Index.aspx is only over HTTP not HTTPS, you will not see the cookie in the collection.